# Audio is not playing for AWS s3 bucket video played through PHP Streaming file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, audio, safari, video-streaming

I have uploaded video on AWS s3 bucket and all the content of s3 bucket is private, now i am creating cloudfront signed url and playing a video as PHP Stream.

Below is the code,

```
        header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $audio_content);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        // In case the file was streaming browser may request file in between
        // for seeking file in middle, where audio file was not downloaded completely
        // In such cases we send the proper content-range in bytes

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && false)
        {

            if (preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches))
            {

                $begin = (int) $matches[1];

                if ( ! empty($matches[2]))
                {
                    $ending = (int) $matches[2];
                }
            }
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');


        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $begin;
            $c_end   = $ending;
            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$ending/$size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range  = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];
                $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $ending) ? $ending : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
                exit;
            }
            $begin  = $c_start;
            $ending    = $c_end;
            $length = $ending - $begin + 1;

            fseek($file_pointer, $begin);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }
        $intLength = $ending - ($begin + 1);
        header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $begin . '-' . $ending . '/' . $size);
        header('Content-Length: ' . $intLength);
        // Stream the file
        $file_pointer = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // If we had downloaded file incase where we did not get content length
        // send that file directly instead of fresh new cURL request
        $curl = curl_init($signedUrlCustomPolicy);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_pointer);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, $begin . '-' . $ending);
        curl_exec($curl);
        //fwrite($file_pointer, $resultData);
        curl_close($curl);
```

**Problem here is Audio is not playing in Mac Safari and iPhone Safari**.

Comment: Why not use [AWS's S3 Stream Wrapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-stream-wrapper.html#opening-seekable-streams)? Why do you have an if statement ending in `&& false`? This doesn't appear to handle HEAD requests. What is the value of `$file_pointer` in the second if statement? Can you post what the request and response headers look like when Safari is attempting to play the audio?